# How to make Gulp.src fail if a file is missing?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, node-glob

Our gulp build takes a bunch of libraries installed with bower, then concatenates them with all the code we have distributed across several directories. Here's what it looks like:

```
  var jsFiles = [
    sourcePath + '/config/config.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/lodash/lodash.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/picturefill/dist/picturefill.min.js',
    sourcePath + '/templates/**/*.js',
    sourcePath + '/pages/**/*.js'
  ],

gulp.task('build:js', ['jscs'], function() {
  return gulp.src(jsFiles)
  .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
  .pipe(gulpif(isProd, uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath + '/webresources/js'));
});
```

Our problem is that whenever someone adds new libraries, other developers will encounter problems if they haven't run `bower install` to get the new components. The `scripts.js` gets built without them since it won't mind that one of the globs returns empty, even if it is a named file.

How should this be solved? Is there a way to throw an error if a glob returns zero results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since there didn't seem to be a ready solution for this, I wrote a module to fit our needs.

The [files-exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/files-exist) module allows you to check whether all files in an array are present, throwing an error if any are missing. It returns an identical array on success, so it is simple to drop in place.

```
  var jsFiles = [
    sourcePath + '/config/config.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/lodash/lodash.js',
    sourcePath + '/vendor/picturefill/dist/picturefill.min.js',
    sourcePath + '/templates/**/*.js',
    sourcePath + '/pages/**/*.js'
  ],

filesExist = require('files-exist'),

gulp.task('build:js', ['jscs'], function() {
  return gulp.src(filesExist(jsFiles)) // Throws error if a file is missing
  .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
  .pipe(gulpif(isProd, uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath + '/webresources/js'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, I was missing some features, like single string parameters and the possibility to use the exclamation mark syntax to ignore files. I've send you a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this package IsThere

https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-there

ex.

```
PATHS:
    javascriptCopyNodeModules:
    # - "node_modules/name.min.js"

import IsThere  from 'is-there';

function javascriptCopyNodeModules() {
   if(IsThere(PATHS.javascriptCopyNodeModules)){
      return gulp.src(PATHS.javascriptCopyNodeModules)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js/node_modules'));
    }else{     
      return gulp.src('.');
   }
}
```

since PATHS.javascriptCopyNodeModules is empty (#) return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

PATHS: javascriptCopyNodeModules: # - "node_modules/name.min.js"

import IsThere from 'is-there';

function javascriptCopyNodeModules() { if(IsThere(PATHS.javascriptCopyNodeModules)){ return gulp.src(PATHS.javascriptCopyNodeModules) .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js/node_modules')); }else{
return gulp.src('path_of_file'); } }

Comment: semma thalapathy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-plumber` a gulp plugin to get error while building.

Example to illustrate:

**Step 1:** Install the gulp-plumber:

```
npm i --save-dev gulp-plumber
```

**Step 2:** Require the gulp plmber module in gulpfile:

```
...
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
...
```

**Step 3:** Usage

```
gulp.task('concatFiles', function (done) {
    
    gulp.src(['../a.js', '../b.js', '../c.js'])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('destination.js'))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

    done(); // a callback required in gulp 4
});
```