# Error handler not being reached for gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am uploading and deploying sharepoint packages via gulp.  Sometimes, it's possible that the app catalog folder doesn't exist, and so the upload will fail.  I'd like to just make a note of the error and move on. I've tried to add some error handling to my code but i can't seem to catch it.
I've tried inside the pipe, outside, and also a try / catch just after the for loop.

**Error**

```
Uploading packge to widget catalog...
[14:29:40] Uploading test.sppkg
[14:29:40] INFO: Folder 'AppCatalog' doesn't exist and will be created
[14:29:40] ERROR: StatusCodeError: 403 - {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied."}}}
```

**Gulp Code**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
const spsync = require('gulp-spsync-creds').sync;
const sppkgDeploy = require('node-sppkg-deploy');


for (const site of sites) {
   console.log("Uploading packge to " + site + " catalog...");
       await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          gulp
          .src(folderLocation)
          .pipe(
            spsync({
              username: uname,
              password: pwd,
              site: siteUrl + "/" + site,
              libraryPath: catalogName,
              publish: true,
            })
          )
          .on("finish",() => {
            console.log("Completed upload of:" + name + ". Starting deploy... ");
              sppkgDeploy.deploy({
                username: uname,
                password: pwd,
                absoluteUrl: siteUrl + "/" + site,
                filename: name,
                skipFeatureDeployment: true,
                verbose: false
            });
            resolve();
          })
          .on("error", (e)=>{
            console.log("%%%%%%%%%%FAILED!")
          });
        });
      }
```

Ultimately, I'd like to catch error number 403 ... and just do a simple console.log and move on.
Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong? I'm presently researching gulp plumber(?) in case that's relevant.  But this is my first gulp script so .. just checking with the community in case I've gone astray somewhere.

thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Updated my code so it looks like this:

```
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          gulp
          .src(folderLocation)
          .pipe(
            spsync({
              username: uname,
              password: pwd,
              site: siteCatalogUrl + "/",
              libraryPath: catalogName,
              publish: true,
            }).on("error", e => console.log("==@@@@@@@@THIS HAS BOMBED@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")))
          .on("finish",resolve); 
          });
```

Basically just added error handler for the spsync.  But the code never hits there either.

Comment: try putting the error listener on spsync directly

Comment: @Todd can you give me an example of what you mean?  just pseudo code even?

Comment: .pipe( spsync().on('error', e=> console.log('blah')) )

Comment: kk cool.  i'll give that a try @Todd

Comment: @Todd check out my EDIT 1.  thanks thanks!

Comment: you could try [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) and catch the error in the callback.

Comment: `'error'` will only trigger if it's a stderr. If a program logs an "error" to stdout, gulp can't know that. That seems like what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the first one to have run into this problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822130/gulp-src-onerror-is-not-getting-triggered-when-file-specified-in-s) is a stackoverflow post, and [here](https://gist.github.com/floatdrop/8269868) is another gist post with basically the same problem described. There seem to be two different possibilities. One is to use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber), and the other is to use [files-exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/files-exist). Here is an example of how you can use `files-exists`:

```
try {
    return src(filesExist('foo.js'))
        .pipe(src('foo.js'))
        // continue pipe
} catch (error) {
    // error handling
}
```

I also want to highlight something that I discovered when I experimented with this. If you add the error listener immediately after the `src` stream is created, then the error is caught, so this will work:

```
return src('non-existing.js')
    .on('error', () => { console.log('Caught error') })
    ... more pipe stuff
```

However, if the error listener is added after a `pipe` call, then it will not work, like so:

```
return src('non-existing.js')
    .pipe(/* some pipe action */)
    .on('error', () => { console.log('Will not be caught') })
    ... more pipe stuff
```

Comment: but the issue i'm dealing isn't the local file not existing ... it's the AppCatalog site not being created in sharepoint... So I think the use case you're describing is very different, no?